# AutoHotKey: MonitorCount as trigger?

Tags: autohotkey

I would like my AutoHotKey-script not to be triggered by a keyboard shortcut, but by an event, namely whenever I attach/detach a second monitor. I wrote this little script which correctly determines and displays the number of monitors, but only when I run the script manually:

```
SysGet, MonitorCount, MonitorCount
if (MonitorCount<>lastMonitorCount)
   {
      MsgBox, Monitor Count:`t%MonitorCount%
   }
SysGet, lastMonitorCount, MonitorCount
```

How can I make the `MsgBox` appear automatically whenever the number of active monitors changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've found the answer:

```
while 2>1
{
  SysGet, MonitorCount, MonitorCount
  if (MonitorCount<>lastMonitorCount)
     {
        MsgBox, Monitor Count:`t%MonitorCount%
     }
  SysGet, lastMonitorCount, MonitorCount
}
```

Comment: SetTimer consumes much less CPU because of the period (It checks every 500 ms). Try adding `Sleep, 500` or more within your while-loop to have the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

Set up a timer that will pop up the message box whenever the number of attached monitors changes:

```
#Persistent                          ; prevents the script from exiting when it reaches the 'Return'
SetTimer, DetectMonitorCount, 500    ; check every 500 milliseconds

    DetectMonitorCount:              ; this is a label
SysGet, MonitorCount, MonitorCount
if (MonitorCount <> lastMonitorCount)
    MsgBox, Monitor Count:`t%MonitorCount%
SysGet, lastMonitorCount, MonitorCount
Return                               ; ends the subroutine
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can `SetTimer` or loop... but `OnMessage` is a better solution.

More details in this post: https://superuser.com/questions/635526/run-a-script-when-second-monitor-is-connected/